# Android Ble, Pheriperal Advertise status during the scan

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application I need to start some BLE scans, get the results and then show them in a list or in a grid.

When i start the scan my device start to look for advertisements basing on which ScanFilters I wrote.

Every time a Pheriperal is found I the application trigger the scan callback method and i can add the new device into the list.

If i got an error the app trigger the callback method and i can tell the user about the broblem.

**Example**

*Imagine the Scan going on for 30s.
At the moment it starts i get 3 Ble Pheriperal.
At second 15 one of them stop to advertise and turn bluetooth off.
At the end of the scan my list will have 3 Ble devices but i will not be able to connect to one of them.*

**How do I know which of them is the one which turned off?
Where do i get his status?**

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, technically it is possible as per the documentation. in `onScanResult` callback, check for the `callbackType` parameter. If it is [CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html#CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST) then get the device from the `results` and remove it from your cache.

Comment: It works. If i set  CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOSTi get notifyed when i lost signal from mt pheriperal. But now i don't get notifyed when i get the first advertisement from the device D:

Comment: You don't need to set it as filter. Just check the callback type when onscanresult gets triggered. If this doesn't work then try to OR the callback types while setting the filter

Comment: if i don't set CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST as a filter the callback onscanresult only return CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES. So i can't distinguish between normal advertisement and match lost advertisement

Comment: Oh my bad. Can't you OR the callback type first and callback type match lost and set the filter. I guess its possible. Try it out.

Comment: No, i didn't. I just set CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES and then i filtered the results with a handler.